# Returning a value from a function within a for-loop

Tags: javascript, function, loops, dom, conditional-statements

I want to run a for-loop that appends every hundredth numeric value of the width of the screen into a div. This works:

```
for (var i = 50, numbers = ""; i < limit; i+= 50) {
  if (num % 100 === 0) {
    numbers += i;
  }
}

document.getElementsByClassName("width")[0].innerHTML = numbers;
```

But when I try to invoke a function within the loop it doesn't:

```
for (var i = 50, numbers = ""; i < limit; i+= 50) {
  insertVal(i, numbers);
}

document.getElementsByClassName("width")[0].innerHTML = numbers;

function insertVal(i, container) {
  if (i % 100 === 0) {
    container += i;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what the return value should be so that the numeric values are being inserted into the div.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/un9uj7nb/3/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *A* set `numbers` in the loop and you need to *B* return `container` from your function,

```
for (var i = 50, numbers = ""; i < limit; i += 50) {
    numbers = insertVal(i, numbers); // A
}

document.getElementsByClassName("width")[0].innerHTML = numbers;

function insertVal(i, container) {
    if (i % 100 === 0) {
        container += i;
    }
    return container; // B
}
```

However, this is less efficient than your working loop as each function call is expensive

---

The way you're passing `numbers` around in this is likely to get confusing if you ever come back to this code at a later date. If it's necessary to use a function here, you may want to consider one of these two code patterns instead

Test as it's own method giving a *Boolean (equivalent)* value so you know the inputs were okay

```
function test(i) {
    return i % 100;
}

for (var i = 50, numbers = ""; i < limit; i += 50) {
    if (test(i))
        numbers += i;
}

document.getElementsByClassName("width")[0].innerHTML = numbers;
```

Test gives a result which may be a transformation on the input that you're interested in or an expected wrong result, e.g. `null`

```
function test(i) {
    if (i % 100)
        return i;
    return null;
}

for (var i = 50, numbers = "", e; i < limit; i += 50) {
    e = test(i);
    if (e !== null)
        numbers += e;
}

document.getElementsByClassName("width")[0].innerHTML = numbers;
```

---

> @CarlEdwards deduplication is an acceptable reason to write functions for these. However, if the loop is almost exactly the same consider if you can move the `for` itself into the loop too

Consider this example where the loop is inside the function `my_loop`, meaning you can reuse the code but are only invoking the function twice

```
function my_loop(i, j) {
    for (var numbers = ""; i < j; i+= 50) {
        if (i % 100 === 0) {
            numbers += i;
        }
    }
    return numbers;
}

document.getElementsByClassName("width")[0].innerHTML = my_loop(50, limit);
document.getElementsByClassName("width")[1].innerHTML = my_loop(250, limit2);
```

Comment: @CarlEdwards Your initial working method was exactly that; to reduce function calls you'd try to avoid invoking a function in a loop or see if you could move the loop into the function instead of around it.

Comment: I see. The reason why I made a function vs. explicitly writing the conditional in the loop was that I was planning on using that same code for an additional loop and didn't want to create too much duplication. I guess there's no way around it if I go that route?

Comment: @CarlEdwards deduplication is an acceptable reason to write functions for these. However, if the loop is almost exactly the same consider if you can move the `for` itself into the loop too

Comment: Not sure I understood the last part of your statement.

Comment: @CarlEdwards please see the new section to my answer I've added in an edit

Comment: I see now. Thanks so much for the thorough breakdown. +1

Answer (score 0):

Return `container` from your function, and pass it back around.

https://jsfiddle.net/un9uj7nb/5/

```
for (var i = 50, numbers = ""; i < limit; i+= 50) {
    numbers = insertVal(i, numbers);
}

document.getElementsByClassName("width")[0].innerHTML = numbers;

function insertVal(i, container) {
    if (i % 100 === 0) {
        container += i;
    }
    return container;
}
```